# Implement a generic that is an object in TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I want to have a onFilterChange helper function that can be used for all filters, so that I dont need to type it for every different filter, but I'm stuck:

```
// helper.ts
export function onFilterChange(prevState: Record<string, any>, fieldName: string, value: string, isDelete = false): Record<string, any> {
  const newFilters: Record<string, any> = { ...prevState };

  if (isDelete) {
    delete newFilters[fieldName];
  } else {
    newFilters[fieldName] = value;
  }

  if (fieldName !== 'page' && 'page' in newFilters) {
    newFilters.page = '1';
  }

  return newFilters;
}

// index.tsx
const [filters, setFilters] = React.useState({page: 1, order: 'desc'});
setFilters(prevState => onFilterChange(prevState, 'statuses', '', true)); // error
```

The error for the last line of code above is:
Type 'Record<string, any>' is missing the following properties from type '{ page: number; order: string; }': page, order

I've also tried T extends Record<string, any> but there is error for this code:

```
newFilters[fieldName] = value;
```

Type string cannot be used to index type T.

Appreciate any pointers. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71552578/17954209) is that if you assert the type, you will not be able to access the value of `filters.statuses` later.

You'll have to type the useState ahead of time

```js
const [filters, setFilters] = React.useState<
  {page: number; order: string; statuses: string}
>({page: 1, order: 'desc'});
```

And change your function to a generic

```js
//Note this generic only extends page, since this is the only
//value we need guranteed, and access directly with the line below
export function onFilterChange<T extends { page: string }>(
  prevState: T,
  fieldName: keyof T,
  value: T[typeof fieldName],
  isDelete = false
): T {
  const newFilters: T = { ...prevState };

  if (isDelete) {
    delete newFilters[fieldName];
  } else {
    newFilters[fieldName] = value;
  }

  if (fieldName !== 'page' && 'page' in newFilters) {
    newFilters.page = '1'; //Here is why T needs to extend {page: string}
  }

  return newFilters;
}
```

Alternatively, if you are setting lots of fields but don't know their type yet you can use the index accessor

```js
const [filters, setFilters] = React.useState<{
  page: number;
  order: string;
} & { [index: string]: string }>({page: 1, order: 'desc'});
```

We have to use an intersection here, otherwise, we'll get an error `Property 'page' of type 'number' is not assignable to 'string' index type 'string'.ts(2411)`.

Also note that TS catches an error here you already made, where the `page` value is a number in your useState, but use reassign it as a string in your function, I don't know if that is intentional or not, but type/fix as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a type assertion like this:

```
// index.tsx
const [filters, setFilters] = React.useState({page: 1, order: 'desc'});
setFilters(prevState => onFilterChange(prevState, 'statuses', '', true) as typeof prevState); // Ok
```